# How to put a line around the border of an HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to add a border to my HTML CANVAS and thought that the following code would do that.

**Question: How can I put a border around the Canvas in the code and in the HTML code>**

Code:

```
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
```

The following code is the whole HTML file. It wasn't all that large so I just pasted it all in.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Chapter 4 Example 1: Image Basics</title>
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);  

function eventWindowLoaded() {
    canvasApp();
}

function canvasSupport () {
    return Modernizr.canvas;
}

function canvasApp(){
    if (!canvasSupport()) {
             return;
    }else{
        var theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = theCanvas.getContext('2d');

        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';

        context.font = '20pt Verdana';
        context.fillText('Some text', 50, 50);
        context.strokeText('Some text', 50, 50);

        context.fill();
        context.stroke();
    }

    var spaceShip=new Image();
    spaceShip.src="ship1.png";
    spaceShip.addEventListener('load', eventShipLoaded , false);

    function eventShipLoaded() {
        drawScreen();
    }

    function drawScreen() {
         context.drawImage(spaceShip, 10, 10);
         context.drawImage(spaceShip, 50, 50);
         context.drawImage(spaceShip, 150, 50);
    }
}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
        Your browser does not support the HTML 5 Canvas. 
    </canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 28):

You could use CSS. Here is an example. http://jsfiddle.net/amER5/1/

```
#canvas {

    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

or inline:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML 5 Canvas. 
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 25):

If you want to embed the border in the canvas then simply call:

```
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/U86Ja/)**

after setting `strokeStyle` and optionally `lineWidth`. In this case you would have to update the border each time you clear the canvas.

If you simply want a border around the canvas and it is not important to be a part of the canvas' bitmap itself (in case you want to save out images) simply apply CSS to the canvas element:

```
theCanvas.style.border = '1px solid #000'; // adjust as needed
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/9JDLv/)**

or directly with CSS style in the tag or as a CSS rule.
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/9Vt33/)**

I would recommend rather though setting the border on the *parent* element (using a CSS rule) as borders (and padding) can affect mouse positions if adjusted with `getBoundingClientRect()`.
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Z4ewE/)**

Comment: gosh did i spend a long time figuring this out, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a border via CSS in the same way you would add a border to anything with CSS:

```
<canvas style="border:1px solid #000000;" widt...
```

inline should do.